# VS2012, SQL Server CE 3.5 with Edmx

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I have a program that we distribute to our customer base that uses a SQL Server CE 3.5 database. We recently upgraded our VS from 2010 to 2012. Now I need to modify the database slightly. I understand that VS2012 no longer supports SQL Server CE 3.5, however to upgrade to 4.0 will take me a large chunk of time.

Is there any way to add fields to my EDMX manually? I am able to alter my database with a script but I would like my EDMX to match so I don't have to make more calls to my database.

I have tried adding the field manually, however when I make a call to that table I get an invalid column error. I had already added the field to the database file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the project with the edmx in VS2010, replace it with a new one based on the updated database structure, open the project in VS 2012

Comment: Marking this as answer since this is what I did. I did an upgrade to windows 8 and had to reinstall vs2010. Other than that it worked great. Thank you